# R: group each column by itself then count by group (repeat for all columns in dataset)

Tags: r

So I'm coming back to R after a little time away and finding myself a bit rusty here. I've had a look around but can't seem to find a way to do this.

I have a dataset that look like df below and what I want is to group each column by itself, get the count for each group then get the percentage for each factor in the column and repeat the same process for all the columns in the dataset and end up with one data frame.

The below gives me what I want for the one column (in this case a). However, I cant think of the best way to reproduce this across multiple columns, where each column is grouped by itself, so b by b, c by c, d by d, etc, without doing it all manually. Where the end result would be one_col but with many rows.

```r
#data
a<- rep(1:5, 5) 
b <- rep(1:5, 5) 
c <- rep(1:5, 5) 
d <- rep(1:5, 5) 
df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)

head(df)

#example analysis on one column
library(tidyverse)
one_col<-df%>%
  group_by(a)%>%
  summarise(count=n())%>%
  spread(a, count)%>%
  mutate(sum=rowSums(.[1:5]), neg=(`1`+`2`)/sum, pos=(`4`+`5`)/sum, neut=`3`/sum)%>%
  select(pos, neg, neut)

one_col
```

I had thought of doing a for loop but struggling with the formatting of it.  Any ideas?

```r
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {       
  group_by(!!df[i,])%>%
    summarise(count=n())
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches using for loop and `purrr::map_dfr()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df |> 
  mutate(across(a:d, ~ case_when(
    . %in% c(1, 2) ~ "neg",
    . %in% c(4, 5) ~ "pos",
    . == 3 ~ "neut"
  )))

# FOR LOOP
l <- vector("list", ncol(df1))
for (i in seq_along(df1)) {
  l[[i]] <- table(df1[[i]]) |> 
    prop.table() |> 
    as.data.frame()
}

l |> 
  setNames(names(df1)) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "var") |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = var, names_from = Var1, values_from = Freq)

# map_dfr()
df1 |> 
  map_dfr(
    ~ table(.x) |> 
      prop.table() |> 
      as.data.frame(),
    .id = "var"
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = var, names_from = .x, values_from = Freq)

# var     neg  neut   pos
# <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a       0.4   0.2   0.4
# 2 b       0.4   0.2   0.4
# 3 c       0.4   0.2   0.4
# 4 d       0.4   0.2   0.4
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! the map_dfr solution is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't work out.